# Angular Popup not showing after navigation to new route

Tags: angular

This issue is very critical in Angular from my view

Iam working with Angular 4 in my application

I want to show a popup it should be displayed 
when i get the API Response. it may be success/failure/warning/info

My Idea: Create component and open it when we get response from API
and My Application requirement is popup should not close until the 
user perform some action on displayed popup.(this action will provide by giving buttons on popup)

Requirement 1: After getting API Response i am navigating to other route, Popup should show on top of new route and it should   not be close until user perform some action.

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/GmOUPtXYpzaY81qJjbHp?p=preview][1]
```

if the above plunkr is userfull consider.
if not usefull please provide me another example

Comment: When exactly do you want to show popup? 
1- When the response comes
2- After the response, u navigate to another page then show popup?

Comment: after getting response i am showing popup and along with showing popup i am navigating (new route , popup both should render and popup should not close until user give some action )

Comment: This is a bogus way of showing a popup, it's logically wrong. U can show popup and after action move t next view. 

Just take a scenario, suppose an error occurred, u want a functionality of retry, you can achieve it very easily if u are on the same page if u don't want to retry provide cancel to navigate at another page. 
If you'll show popup and navigate together, it will not display because navigation loads different HTML.

Comment: thanks @Ashsih will work and give update  please provide your response

Comment: Sure, always welcome

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't critical, you just do it wrong.

Of course, if you display a pop-up on the routed component, it will disappear. That's not a critical Angular issue, that's poor thinking (no offense though).

The correct way of displaying a pop-up in single page applications is to append the pop-up to the body, in an absolute position. If you do it in the routed component, then on route change, the component gets destroyed, and so is the pop-up.

Comment: thanks @trichetriche, will work and give update please provide your response